# Spring Boot Hibernate Combine Annotations into one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I basically would like to turn this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "edu_course")
public class EduCourse {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="course_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(
        name="course_seq",
        sequenceName="course_sequence",
        allocationSize=20
    )
    private int id;
}
```

into this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "edu_course")
public class EduCourse {
    @SequenceId(name = "course")
    private int id;
}
```

I tried different things but I always end up with the complier warning: "This annotation is not applicable to target 'annotation class'".
Is that somehow possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create meta-annotations in the current spec.

Take a look at `@Id` annotation:

```java
@Target({METHOD, FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)

public @interface Id {}
```

`ANNOTATION_TYPE` is not listed as a possible target, which is why you receive "This annotation is not applicable to target 'annotation class'" error.

There is an open issue [Allow type level annotations to be used as meta-annotations #43](https://github.com/jakartaee/persistence/issues/43) created in 2013, sadly it is still not implemented in 2023.

Comment: Too bad... So the usual way in spring boot now is to add all three Annotation for every entity?

Comment: AFAIK yes, you need all three.